# Pandas add new column with CumSum of two columns, restart with new value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
A    B    C
1    10   2
1    15   0
2    5    2
2    5    0
```

I add column D through:

```
df["D"] =  (df.B - df.C).cumsum()

A    B    C   D
1    10   2   8
1    15   0   23
2    5    2   26
2    5    0   31
```

I want the cumsum to restart in row 3 where the value in column A is different from the value in row 2.
Desired output:

```
A    B    C   D
1    10   2   8
1    15   0   23
2    5    2   3
2    5    0   8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
df['new'] = (df.B-df.C).groupby(df.A).cumsum()
Out[343]: 
0     8
1    23
2     3
3     8
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby and cumsum

```
df['D'] = df.assign(D=df['B']-df['C']).groupby('A')['D'].cumsum()

   A   B  C   D
0  1  10  2   8
1  1  15  0  23
2  2   5  2   3
3  2   5  0   8
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2, 2], "B": [10, 15, 5, 5], "C": [2, 0, 2, 0]})

df['D'] = df['B'] - df['C']
df = df.groupby('A').cumsum()
print(df)
```

output:

```
    B  C   D
0  10  2   8
1  25  2  23
2   5  2   3
3  10  2   8
```